# WooComeerce Productos - Variables

Tags: woocommerce

necesito agregarle a mis productos en wooComeerce un valor de comision que sera privado solo se le mostrara a los administradores esos valores para eso entre a mi consola de woocomeerce y agrege un atributo valorComision

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando termino mi compra y miro mi tabla  no veo estos datos guardados, solamente aparecen si hago que se vean en la pagina chequeando "usado para variaciones Visibles en la pagina de productos"

pero la idea es que sea interno y se guarden en la base de datos,

Nose si estoy mareado en el uso de atributos o si me estoy perdiendo algo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y preguntaste en woocomerce? esto que estas preguntando es configuracion de un plugin.. y aca contestamos cosas sobre programacion....

Comment: Para el caso, hay un sitio particular de wordpress en la red..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los atributos en woocommerce no son lo que se llama Extra Cargos y es por ello que no aparecen como monto agregado en la tabla de ordenes, para ello debes instalar un plugin llamado YITH WooCommerce Product Add-ons, esto te va a permitir agregar complementos o servicos los cuales puedes especificar que sean aplicados a todos los productos de tú catalogo o a uno en particular, y en este mismo plugin puedes establecer reglas de visibilidad y decidir si las opciones serán visibles para todos los usuarios (incluidos los invitados) o si solo pueden ser vistas por usuarios registrados o solo por roles de usuario específicos.

Aqui tienes un enlace de como manejar dicho plugin https://www.webempresa.com/blog/complementos-productos-woocommerce-como-anadirlos.html